# How do I get this 'missing letters' function to work in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on this ['Missing letters'](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/missing-letters) challenge on [Free Code Camp.](https://www.freecodecamp.com) The challenge indicates the following:

> Find the missing letter in the passed letter range and return it.
>
> If all letters are present in the range, return undefined.

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var newstr;
   for(var j = 0; j < str.length; j++){

       var previous = str.charCodeAt(j);
       var next = str.charCodeAt(j) + 1;


        if(next === false){
            newstr = String.fromCharCode(next);
        } else {
             return undefined;
       }
   }

  return newstr;
}
```

Thought I nailed it initially,

```
   var previous = str.charCodeAt(j);
   var next = str.charCodeAt(j) + 1;
```

Simply—if `next` is not true, e.g. the value of `next` is not the subsequent character or one more than previous, return `newstr = String.fromCharCode(next);`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++)
  {
    if(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1 != str.charCodeAt(i+1))
        return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

In general setting and returning unnecessary variables is not good practice. You are not testing any condition in your if statement either. You need to actually compare the value of the character of the first index with the second. Also, since you need to compare 2 indices, your iteration must stop at go inclusive on

```
[0, length - 2] with a + 1 for the secondary index
```

or

```
[1, length - 1] with a - 1 for the secondary index
```

A Note on going to length - 1:

consider the character in the string "abcd":

```
a, b, c, d
0, 1, 2, 3
```

if i loop on [0, 3] when i try to access

```
str[i+1] // index 4
```

I will get an index out of bounds exception when i = 3
or if am index out of bounds exception when i = 0 if i try to access

```
str[i-1] // index -1
```

That is why i only iterate to one away from the given boundary

Comment: Thanks! Few questions.
Why in the loop's condition did you do `str.length - 1`? Don't you want the loop to go through the entire length of the string?

Not sure I understand your if statement; Could you please explain? I would think you'd want to compare if the subsequent value would logically follow the previous value. (Which is why I came up with those `previous` and `next` variables) I know `str.charCodeAt(i) + 1 != str.charCodeAt(i+1)` are different syntax wise but my brain sees them as the same. But thanks so much for responding! Been working a while on this one!

Comment: The note at the bottom of my answer was supposed to explain that; I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. I'll edit the answer to explain better.

Comment: @thedevelop3rThanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution to be quite easy to interpret:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var missingLetter;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) - str.charCodeAt(i-1) > 1) {
      missingLetter = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) - 1);
    }
  }
  return missingLetter;
}
```